# How to recover from accidental chmod 777 on /etc/sudoers

Tags: sudo

I am having a problem with an install of retropie on a raspberry pi where I have accidentally locked out the `sudo` command.

I am about to just re-image my pi and start over unless someone can help me get out of this pickle. The problem is that I accidentally changed the permissions on `/etc/sudoers` to 777 and now ALL attempts to use `sudo` command at all fail with

```
sudo: /etc/sudoers is world writable
sudo: no valid sudoers sources found. quitting
sudo: unable to initialize policy plugin
```

I read elsewhere that you can fix this by using `pkexec 775 /etc/sudoers` but the problem there is that the root user on retropie is disabled by default and `pkexec` works exclusively as the root user.

I have also not been able to find out what the password is for the root user on a retropie image as all queries for that lead to answers like

> You dont need to use root user, use pi user.

Comment: Related, if not a dupes: 1) [How can I revert a chmod on the etc directory?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/84090) 2) [How to restore to permissions to sudoers file with no password?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/203839)

Comment: By design, there are lots of things you can't easily do without root access. Provided you have **physical** access, its not difficult to regain root access.

Answer (score 0):

Since `/etc/sudoers` is owned by root, you would need sudo to fix this.

On a "normal" system, you could fix this by booting from an install disk, mounting `/` (on the flash drive) as `/mnt`, running chmod 440 `/mnt/etc/sudoers` (as sudo).

It might be worth trying this on an external system (being very careful) for the Rasberry Pi, *just for practice*. Obviously it would be quicker to burn a fresh flash card.

Comment: Well I decided that I didnt want to deal with any sleeper issues with the /etc folder and all its recursive children having bad permissions (that is how I accidentally messed up trying to 777 the entire /etc folder).  So I just started with a fresh image and got back to where I was in about 20 minutes.

Comment: A lot of stuff in /etc is very sensitive to permissions e.g. `ssh`